# 32feet.net: Invalid argument supplied - Parani module

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, bluetooth, 32feet

I'm experiencing problems with Windows 8: the following code has always worked with previous versions of Windows.

```
BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(_myAddress,PIN);
_BTClient.Connect(_myAddress,InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothService.SerialPort);
return _BTClient.GetStream();
```

The "Connect" method always throw an Exception

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketsException: {"An invalid argument was supplied             *_myAddress*:0000110100001000800000805f9b34fb"}."

The Discovery is working fine so I suppose the BT Radio is working.

The hardware is a "Dell Wireless 380 Bluetooth 4.0 Module".

I'm connecting to a a Parani Module ESD100V2

Thanks for any solution/advice/hint you may give.

Answer (score 0):

Does the PairRequest you do return true or false?

Anyway, Parani devices I've worked with in the past have a bug for connect when not paired. So, to check that, pair manually through the Windows UI and see if the connect works then.